# Куда в основном поступают(,) после окончания, если не секрет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Перед "после" ставится запятая?

Например: **Куда в основном поступают, после окончания, если не секрет?**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 5):

Нет, не ставится.

*После окончания* - это косвенное дополнение, не требующее обособления.

Comment: Обстоятельство времени.

Comment: @Niemand было бы замечательно, если бы вы привели аргументы.

Comment: "поступают (когда?) после окончания". Проще пареной репы.

Comment: @Niemand «поступают (после чего?) после окончания»...

Comment: такие искусственные вопросы к членам предложения никогда не ставятся. Этому в школе учат. Можно поставить естественный вопрос к обстоятельству -- значит, обстоятельство. К определению - значит, определение. Что вы скажете о таком, например, определении: "ветки (какие?) дерева"? Это именно определение, а не дополнение.

Comment: @Niemand «**На березе** появились первые листочки» -- как в школе учат, что такое _на березе_?

Comment: Естественно, это обстоятельство места. Не верите? Спросите хотя бы на Грамоте.

Comment: @Niemand не верю. Называются такие «бесспорные» словосочетания _обстоятельственными дополнениями_. Прошу вас обратить на это внимание.